# Save dictionary to file

Tags: python

I have a file looking like this:

```
732772  scaffold-3  G   G   A
732772  scaffold-2  G   G   A
742825  scaffold-3  A   A   G
776546  scaffold-3  G   A   G
776546  scaffold-6  G   A   G
```

I'm interested in using column 2 as my key, and output in a way that: having a unique key, and assiociated with it values.

in other words, if name in column 2 occurs more than once, output it only once, therefore the output should be:

```
scaffold-3
732772   G  G   A
742825   A  A   G
776546   G  A   G
scaffold-2
732772   G  G   A
scaffold-6
776546   G  A   G
```

I wrote sth like this:

```
res = open('00test','r')
out = open('00testresult','w')

d = {}
for line in res:
    if not line.startswith('#'):
        line = line.strip().split()
        pos = line[0]
        name = line[1]
        call = line[2]
        father = line[3]
        mother = line[4]

        if not (name in d):
            d[name] = []
        d[name].append({'pos':pos,'call':call,'father':father,'mother':mother})
```

but I have no idea, how to output it in a way I described above.

Any help will be nice

EDIT:

This is fully working code, that solved the problem:

```
res = open('00test','r')
out = open('00testresult','w')

d = {}
for line in res:
    if not line.startswith('#'):
        line = line.strip().split()
        pos = line[0]
        name = line[1]
        call = line[2]
        father = line[3]
        mother = line[4]

        if not (name in d):
            d[name] = []
        d[name].append({'pos':pos,'call':call,'father':father,'mother':mother})

for k,v in d.items():
    out.write(str(k)+'\n')
    for i in v:
        out.write(str(i['pos'])+'\t'+str(i['call'])+'\t'+str(i['father'])+'\t'+str(i['mother'])+'\n')

out.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you have your dictionary, loop over the items and write to a file:

```
keys = ('pos', 'call', 'father', 'mother')

with open(outputfilename, 'w') as output:
    for name in d:
        output.write(name + '\n')
        for entry in d['name']:
            output.write(' '.join([entry[k] for k in keys]) + '\n')
```

You may want to use a [`collections.defaultdict()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) object instead of a regular dictionary for `d`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
```

and *remove* the `if not (name in d): d[name] = []` lines altogether.

Comment: sorry this didn't help a bit. I can print it in a way i want, but when it comes down to saving to the file like i statetd, it just doesn't work.

Comment: @Irek: it wasn't clear that the output had to be to a *file*. Updated.

Comment: Ok I took the last part for my use. Thanks, this solution works. I will edit my post with working code